# Создание *.txt с кодировкой UTF-8 без BOM по умолчанию

Tags: notepad++

Добрый день

В Notepad++ есть отличный параметр в "Опции - Настройки - Новый документ", где можно выставить создание файла с нужной кодировкой. Если **создавать txt в самом редакторе**, то вопросов нет, всё ок.

Но часто txt создаётся или через контекстное меню или Shift+F4 в Total Commander. В обоих случаях в созданном файле, открытом сразу же в Notepad++, кодировка ANSI и её ещё нужно не забыть поменять.

Пробовал делать [вот так](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/default-utf-8-encoding-for-new-notepad-documents/525f0ae7-121e-4eac-a6c2-cfe6b498712c), но такой вариант не работает. Может быть кто-то подскажет альтернативный путь?

Comment: Вы _точно_ уверены, что это вопрос по программированию?

Answer (score 1):

К

> Settings -> Preferences -> New Document
>
> UTF8- without BOM

поставить галку

> Apply to opened ANSI files

PS: Проверенно именно на <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> в Total Commander, ибо сам пользуюсь данной связкой и с этой настройкой.

Answer (score 0):

В Notepad++ 6.5.5 Это делает тут

Settings -> Preferences -> New Document

Encoding нужно выбрать UTF-8 b галочку without BOM

Comment: Не по теме, однако, совет, забудьте об этой версии, пока не огребли проблем. Самая стабильная 6.3, Build Feb 3 2013. В ней также имеется и эта настройка и упомянутая мною галка "Apply to opened ANSI files". Зато, отсутствует баг в реплейсе, присутсвующий во всех последующих по текущую.